# How to enable access to a Windows 10 shared folder from android VLC?

Tags: windows, windows-10, android, network-shares, vlc-media-player

Let's say I have this `H:\Films` directory that I should like to have access to from my mobile (Android) VLC player.

On Windows 10, I created a local user, `stream` and created a password for it.

Then I went into the `Network & Sharing Center` and made sure that `Turn on file and printer sharing` was selected in both, `private` and `guest or public (current profile)` and that `turn on password protected sharing` was on in `all networks` (with an `128bit encryption`).

Next I go to the `H:\Films` directory's properties and under `advanced sharing` select `share this folder` then in permissions, remove "Everyone"  and instead add read access for the `stream` user only.

Alright, according to windows, this folder should now be accessible on `\\MY_COMPUTER\Films`.

I open up VLC on android and select the `Local Network` tab.

`MY_COMPUTER` shows up as an `smb` folder.

I click on it, expecting to be asked for credentials as is the case for other smb servers ... except I'm not being asked. There's just this circular loading icon spinning ad infinitum.

Tried with the windows firewall turned off, didn't make a difference.

Tried with full access to the folder for `everyone`, didn't make a difference.

How do I allow VLC to connect to this folder?

Comment: In `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings` in HomeGroup connections  switch to `Use user accounts` instead of "Allow windows to manage...". Depending on version of your VLC you might want to switch to `Enable file sharing for devices that use 40-56 bit encryptions`. Your VLC also might not support SMB3 latest protocol in Win10, you might need to enable then in "Programs and features->Turn Windows feature..." old CIFS protocol, if you sure no one would try to exploit its vulnerability

Comment: @Alex there's no ``HomeGroup connections`` options in the ``advanced sharing settings`` of the ``Network and Sharing Center``. Switching to 40-56bit encryption didn't do anything.

Comment: @Alex old CIFS seems to have done the trick, giving me access, thank you. Want to make an answer out of it?

Comment: Yeah, it's a good idea, may be some1 would need it too.

Comment: My problem was different. I got a login prompt but it blocked all username/password. However it was solved without any protocol change, so it's worth a try. See https://superuser.com/questions/1474464/.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

VLC probably doesn't support latest Windows SMB3 protocol. Go to:

```
Control Panel=>Programs and Features
```

and click on the left pane "Turn windows features on or off" and check `CIFS` old protocol. Make sure that nobody would try to exploit its vulnerability.

Comment: i love you man.. spent 2 hours almost... until i saw the remedy... Bravo!

Comment: VLC devs could do better than requiring this 30 year old protocol to be enabled in order to make things work. Microsoft themselves urge people to disable it: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/filecab/2016/09/16/stop-using-smb1/

Comment: @andromeda947 One of developer of VLC answered that they planing to support SMB2/3 in VLC ver.4.x

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is reading this in the future, newer versions of VLC on Android and iOS have an option called "Prefer SMB v1" that's enabled by default, disabling that option lets VLC access shares that use newer SMB versions meaning it can access Windows shares without having to enable CIFS/SMBv1 on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

In your Computer:

1. Make sure your Computer (i.e. **MYPC**, **192.168.1.2**, etc.) and your Folder (i.e. **\MYPC\MyFolder**, **\192.168.1.2\MyFolder**, etc.) are indeed shared over your LAN, using your **user** and **password**,

In VLC:

1. Go to *Browse>"Three Dots Menu">Add a server favorite*,
2. Enter the following, and press *OK*,

   - Type: *SMB*,
   - Network Share Name: **MYPC**,
   - Server Name: **My Server**,
   - (No Port).
3. Go to *Browser>Favorites>**My Folder**>"Three Dots Menu">Edit*, and press *OK*,

   - Username: **user:password**
4. Go to *More>Settings>Advanced>Prefer SMB 1* and uncheck it.

Comment: what about public shares, no user or pass?